# In R package 'cclust' is there an equivalent of 'nstart' option from the 'kmeans' package?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am trying to do k-means clustering in R using the cclust package.
In k-means clustering, the initial centroid assignment greatly affects the final allocation. The kmeans package has an nstart option, which guarantees that your results are based on 'nstart' number of initial configurations. Is there an equivalent option for the same in the cclust package?

Thanks.

TAK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately no,**

Cclust has been written as a wrapper for different clustering method.
It does not call the *stats::kmeans* function but call instead a homemade kmaens function which doesn't include any equivalent of the "*nstart*" argument.

I suggest you to use a kmeans function from another package

PS : I assume you mentioned *kmeans* function from R basic package "stats".

Source : https://github.com/cran/cclust/blob/master/src/cclust.c